# Data truncated for column startDate1 at row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns startdate and enddate of type int. These columns are used to store timestamp data.

Now I have to extract the date component from this timestamp, convert it back to timestamp an store it in another column startdate1 of type int

But on doing this, I get a warning 'Data truncated for column startDate1 at row'.

The sql queries are:-

```
ALTER TABLE `ServiceRule` ADD COLUMN `startDate1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `endDate` , ADD COLUMN `endDate1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `startDate1`;

update `ServiceRule` set `startDate1`= TIMESTAMP(DATE(from_unixtime(`startDate`)));
update `ServiceRule` set `endDate1`= TIMESTAMP(DATE(from_unixtime(`endDate`)));
```

Now if i change the datatype of startDate1 and endDate1 to TIMESTAMP, the first update query of startDate1 runs successfully.
But the endDate1 update query shows the warning 'Out of range value for column 'endDate1' at row'.

After browsing for solution, i got know that this occurs if the input value is greater than the column datatype range.

Can anybody please try to help me out?
Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is the inverse function of `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Answer (score 1):

What means that one of the rows contains a value that cannot be converted to `int` because indeed it is either too more or too less than expected.

Can't you just convert the columns to `timestamp` and do the extraction from there? Try to query per set of 100 for example and narrow down the faulting row.

Answer (score 1):

When the field `startDate` is of type `int`, then `alter table` statement used is not correct to achieve what you wanted.

Change it as below:

```
-- keeping the added fields as is, execute the following  

ALTER TABLE `ServiceRule` MODIFY COLUMN `startDate1` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `ServiceRule` MODIFY COLUMN `endDate1` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;

update `ServiceRule` set `startDate1`= TIMESTAMP(DATE(from_unixtime(`startDate`)));
update `ServiceRule` set `endDate1`= TIMESTAMP(DATE(from_unixtime(`endDate`)));
```